# How to choose top 50 % of pdf page?

Tags: graphics, crop

I would like to select the top part (50 %) of the PDF document and put two of such documents one after another. 
The bottom 50 % is blank.

Here an example code which lists two PDF documents side by side, but the font size gets too small.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=\textwidth]{{P100C1}.pdf}
\caption{P100 C1.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=\textwidth]{{P100C2}.pdf}
\caption{P100 C2.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Descriptive statistics.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Testing Werner's approach

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\adjustbox{trim=0 .5\height{} 0 0, clip, width=.3\linewidth} % show top 50\%
    {\includegraphics[page=2,width=\textwidth]{{P100C1}.pdf}}
\caption{P100 C1.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\adjustbox{trim=0 .5\height{} 0 0, clip, width=.3\linewidth}
    {\includegraphics[page=2,width=\textwidth]{{P100C2}.pdf}}
\caption{P100 C2.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Descriptive statistics.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output correct (where just decreased size)

[image]

### Testing Dan's answer

Output: Something is cropped from the sides

[image]

TeXLive: 2016
Debian: 8.5

Comment: I don't recognize this syntax for the `subfigure` environment. What package defines it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides access to the image dimensions, specifically `\height`. Use this as part of your `trim`-and-`clip` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \qquad
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}%

  \bigskip

  \adjustbox{trim=0 .5\height{} 0 0, clip, width=.3\linewidth}
    {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}% Show top 50%
  \qquad
  \adjustbox{trim=0 0 0 .5\height, clip, width=.3\linewidth}
    {\includegraphics{example-image-b}}% Show bottom 50%

  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`trim=llx lly urx ury` trims the image horizontally `llx` from the left and `urx` from the right, as well as `lly` from the bottom and `ury` from the top.

Comment: @Masi: You do notice that I use `\adjustbox{..., width=.3\linewidth,...}{..}` which shrinks the image horizontally to about 1/3 of the line width, right? You're welcome to change this to suit your needs... I thought you knew this; apparently not.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `viewport` and `clip` options to `\includegraphics`:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
% top half of page 2 of X.pdf
\includegraphics[page=2,viewport=72 396 540 720,width=\textwidth,clip]%
  {X.pdf}
\caption{P100 C1.}
\end{subfigure}\\
% bottom half of page 2 of Y.pdf
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,viewport=72 72 540 396,width=\textwidth,clip]%
  {Y.pdf}
\caption{P100 C2.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Descriptive statistics.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This works! Confirmed. Can the document be zoomed out little this way. It seems that it crops something at the right hand side too.

Comment: @Masi You can adjust the `viewport` data: the numbers represent the coordinates (in postscript points) of the lower left and the upper right of the visible area. To widen it on the right, change the 540 to something larger. I find that `viewport` doesn't always seem to behave as I would expect. You may have to tinker with it and the other parameters.